# $(...).multiselect is not a function error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, multi-select

I've researched this issue extensively, and can't seem to find a solution. I am attempting to auto populate a multiselect box based on the second box, and have to call

`$('#state').multiselect('rebuild');`

yet it returns

`$(...).multiselect is not a function error`

in console.

I am importing the following libraries:

```
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.18/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

           <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.18/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```